# How to get back to original spawn when in creative and spawn resets?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a really good castle in creative mode but had not slept in a bed on superflat mode. Someone killed me and that somehow reset my spawn more than once. I did tests in a new world of the same kind of circumstances and found that when killed and not having slept in a bed you respawn in a totally different area. If anyone knows how to get back to my original spawn point I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Minutor](http://seancode.com/minutor/), or some other mapping program to work out the coordinates of your epic castle (in Minutor, the coordinates of the block under the cursor are shown in the status bar at the bottom). Then in-game, press <kbd>F3</kbd> to see your coordinates and walk to the coordinates you found.

*Then sleep in a bed and reset your spawn!!*

Comment: The compass works too to get the the original spawn without installing any tools.

Comment: @fredley Is there any way to simply teleport back to the original spawn (instead of walking perhaps thousands of meters?)

Comment: @AndersonGreen Yes, you can use the `/tp` command and teleport directly to the coordinates you found, e.g. `/tp 345 64 923456`

Comment: How does the compass help get back to spawn? All it does is show you the direction you are facing.

Answer (score 3):

If you built it near your original spawn point, a compass will point you there. You can give yourself one in Creative Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, all I did was follow a compass. I too, was stuck and I had absolutely no idea how to find my whole city I built. All I did was follow a compass and I was back at my city. I went pretty far from my city and it took a while to get back so don't get impatient. It might take a while to get back to you house or whatever it is you built, but you will get there.

Answer (score 0):

The compass points to your initial spawn point (world spawn point). Just point the compass so the red line appears straight ahead as if north and then keep following until you are back to your starting point. If you don't remember what it looks like you will know when the compass keeps pointing back behind you as you try to continue straight ahead.